# Add MVC Controller Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, asp.net-mvc-controller

In Visual Studio 2013, I am missing the add MVC Controller - Empty scaffolding item.

When I right click the controllers folder, then Add, and click the controller option at the top of the menu. The Add Scaffold popup window appears with only a list of Web API 2 controllers to add.

http://postimg.org/image/bz5rze56n/ <--- Image here

Just to see if it is only this project, I created a new empty mvc project and followed the same steps and I did have the mvc controllers in there.

Does anyone know how I can get those options back in my main project? I'd rather not just copy and paste  my existing controllers. :-P

Thank you for any help you may provide!

Comment: do you have all SP installed?

Comment: Yes, everything is up to date. If I create a new project, the options are there... just not in the project I'm currently working on.

Comment: I have this issue too.  Other than updating to MVC 5 not sure how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic, but I found if you instead of using the Add->Controller option in the context menu, but instead use Add->New Item option, then choose MVC Controller and name it, then this also creates the same structure as the Empty Controller template.

Answer (score 0):

shut down all running Visual studio's
run VisualStudio command prompt as admin.
type this:  devenv /installvstemplates